# Dynamic programing with bitmasking

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic, combinatorics, pseudocode

There are N men and N women, both numbered 1,2,…,N

.

For each i,j
(1≤i,j≤N), the compatibility of Man i and Woman j is given as an integer ai,j. If ai,j=1, Man i and Woman j are compatible; if ai,j=0

, they are not.

Taro is trying to make N
pairs, each consisting of a man and a woman who are compatible. Here, each man and each woman must belong to exactly one pair.

how to represent state of dp?

Answer (score 2):

So you have undirected bipartite graph and want to get complete (perfect) matching.

It might be found using [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) (note - it is greedy not DP)

Example of application of DP to perfect matching problem - [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931674/dynamic-programming-to-find-a-match)

Comment: some people have solved it using dp here is the link https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/submissions/10720846. Please explaiin what is the state of dp they have chosen

Comment: But... You have not described that problem has **another** goal - not to find a matching but find number of possible matchings.